# Uploading dwg files to wordpress

Tags: uploads, media

I'm trying to upload files with dwg extension to media but when I do that I get an error telling me that uploading files with this extension is not allowed. I tried to upload them via ftp but I cannot see them in my panel afterwards. I've looked for a solution online and tried adding this to my `functions.php`:

```
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes[‘dwg’] = ‘application/dwg’;
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter(‘upload_mimes’,’custom_upload_mimes’);
```

But it didn't change anything. Is there any other way to bypass this file restriction?

Comment: Is your actual code using `‘` and `’` rather than `'`?

Comment: Initially it was, later I pasted code @Krzysiek Dróżdż suggested but it didn't help. Now I tried using the code from the original code again but with `'` instead but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. The only problem in there is that you’ve set incorrect mime type, I guess...

It should be `image/vnd.dwg`.

So this one should work:

```
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/vnd.dwg';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I'm getting same error which says more or less `Due to safety reasons this file type is not allowed`. I've pasted this at the top of functions.php, maybe I need to put it in a specific place in code?

Comment: Are you sure that you've added it to your active theme? I've just tested that code and it works fine. You can paste it in `functions.php` file of your theme.

Comment: I tried pasting into both availible themes to make sure it was not the problem but it didn't help, I'll try bit more maybe I'm missing something obvious

Comment: @aMJay where and how exactly are you pasting it?

Comment: I tried yet another time copying it the way you said and now it works, I have a feeling I've been doing it exactly the same way before but I guess I must have done something wrong earlier, anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I use this code in wordpress to upload DWG files. It works fine.
But today, we have DWG file from the AUTOCAD 2018. I cannot upload this new version of files. I look in the MINE media types. nothing else than image/vnd.dwg for both version 2013 and 2018 any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If it can help:
to fix the `Due to safety reasons this file type is not allowed` error

you need to add this in the `wp-config.php` :

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

The dwg mimes are multiple, you should add all these:

```
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/vnd.dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/acad';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/autocad';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/autocaddwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'drawing/dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/dwg';

    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: It's a security risk to just allow all file uploads with ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS.

Comment: Also this will only ever return the last ``$existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/dwg';`` as you are redeclaring the same array item each time.