# Adding multiple MIME types of the same extension to WordPress?

Tags: uploads, media-library

I am trying to enable DWG MIME types for WordPress file upload, and tried applying [this filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306873/uploading-dwg-files-to-wordpress/385764#385764?newreg=910320ba83fa451e97192a35fc665639). However, because it's the same array, it won't work and will only apply the final one below. Wondering if there's a way to code it to include all?

```
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/vnd.dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/acad';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/autocad';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/autocaddwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'drawing/dwg';
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'image/dwg';

    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign multiple file-mime-types to extension?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323750/how-to-assign-multiple-file-mime-types-to-extension)